# Are these hardware all compatible with Windows 11?

Tags: compatibility

I was more inclined to laptops, I have been using them for almost 10 years but after a series of events I give up using them and I will give a change to desktops. I am rust when it comes to hardware, before I just searched for laptop that had a processor with more than "1500 benchmark" and more than 4GB of RAM and it was just fine for me to work and study. I am assembling a desktop I would like to know if the motherboard, power supply and processor are compatible.

power supply
https://www.coolermaster.com/br/pt-br/catalog/power-supplies/elite-series/elite-v3-300w/

motherboard
https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/a320m-hdv%20r4.0/index.asp

processor amd athon 3000g

Answer (score 1):

If you get Windows 11, the power supply doesn't matter, its just the cpu needs AMD64 support, and according to the official requirements, also TPM 2.0. That cpu seems to have both, so you should be ok there

Where you probably are not ok, is your motherboard. That motherboard supports the Athlon 3000G only after a BIOS update and it does not support BIOS flashback. If it fits in your budget, try the ASUS Prime A320M-K: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/PRIME/PRIME-A320M-K/